# Java: Regular expression doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, regex, matching

I have the following piece of code:

```
String range = "(15-42)";
String regexp = "(\\d{1,})(\\d{1,})";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher m = p.matcher(range);

m.find();

System.out.println(m.groupCount());

for(int i=0; i<=m.groupCount(); i++){
System.out.println("value:" + m.group());
}
```

And then I have the following output:

```
2
value: 15
value: 1
value: 5
```

But I'm only expecting to see 2 values: 15 and 42.

Why doesn't this work as expected?

Comment: You forgot the hyphen. `String regexp = "(\\d{1,})-(\\d{1,})";`. See http://ideone.com/JeNO2u

Comment: now I see: 2 value: 15-42 value:15 value:42, but I need to have just 15 and 42.

Comment: I did not post an answer because I thought you would delete the question seeing the missing hyphen. I posted an answer because another answer was posted. Well, it is up to you to decide which one is best now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add hyphen to the regex and use `.group(i)` and start with index `1` (because `m.group(0)` is the whole match value that you do not need):

```
String range = "(15-42)";
String regexp = "(\\d{1,})-(\\d{1,})";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher m = p.matcher(range);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.groupCount());
    for(int i=1; i<=m.groupCount(); i++){
        System.out.println("value:" + m.group(i));
    }
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ydyQ8Y)

Now, you will have

```
2               // This is the number of capturing groups
value:15        // This is the value of the first capturing group
value:42        // This is the value of the second capturing group
```

Comment: Just FYI: `{1,}` limiting quantifier is semantically equal to `+` quantifier (*1 or more*), so you can use `String regexp = "(\\d+)-(\\d+)";`

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is that you are always calling `m.group()` when you should be calling `m.group(i)`.

The other mistake is that you forgot the hyphen in your regex.

Working code:

```
String range = "(15-42)";
String regexp = "(\\d{1,})-(\\d{1,})";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher m = p.matcher(range);
m.find();
for (int i = 0; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println("value:" + m.group(i));
}
```

This prints the expected:

```
value:15-42
value:15
value:42
```

Comment: Repeating what I said. But you forgot that OP does not need the zeroth group value.

Comment: @stribizhev Actually, I posted earlier, but it's not relevant.

Comment: I commented 7 minutes ago with a code demo link. You posted 2 mins ago.

Comment: When I saw your comment, it did not mention the fact that the OP did not call `m.group(i)`. But I don't want to argue here, I can delete my answer if you want.

Comment: No, why delete if it is posted, and you have rep for it :). I seem to suffer for my SO answering style.

Comment: @stribizhev Well you seem to take it personally. And again, I don't want to argue. And FYI in your code demo link, you call `m.group()` not `m.group(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Its a different method but you can use this solution

```
    System.out.println(m.groupCount());
    String[] value = m.group().split("-");

    for(int i=0; i<value.length; i++){
    System.out.println("value:" + value[i]);
    }
```